# Grayscale image from external URL

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I want to get external url, transform into grayscale then display it to the browser.

I tried using GD with below code:

```
$youtube_id = explode('&amp;v=', $video['youtube_link'])[1];
                                $image_colour = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/$youtube_id/0.jpg";
                                $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_colour);
                                $image_gray = imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
                                imagejpeg($im, $youtube_id);
```

THis doesn't seem to be working.

Is there any good solution?

Comment: what exactly is not working, please describe the result/error-msg?

Comment: No error message. Just doesn't display the image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display image, you need to set right headers.

I edited your code a bit and here you have a working example:

```
<?php
$video = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aFkZET3A8A";
$url_parts = explode('v=', $video);
$youtube_id = $url_parts[1];
$image_colour = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/$youtube_id/0.jpg";
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_colour);
$image_gray = imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
?>
```

Modify it so it fit your needs. You should also consider using regexp instead of explode (for now it will only work for simple urls with `&v=xyz` phrase at the end).

Comment: I ended up using timthumb for this operation. Thanks for the info anyways